Split with multiple delimiters, and with multiple characters in each delimiter
I would like to split the following string
const hours = '13:00 - 17:00 / 20:00 - 02:00' 

into this array
['13:00', '17:00', '20:00', '02:00']

where there are no spaces, no '/' and no '-'.
I tried with this syntax :
hours.split(' - | / ')

but it doesn't work. And I don't find the good syntax using regex ;(
I would like to do it in one line, and not like that :
hours
.replaceAll(' ','')
.replace('/','-')
.split('-');

Can somebody help ? Thanks !

Does this answer your question? How do I split a string with multiple separators in JavaScript?

What's wrong with regex? hours.split(/[ |/-]+/)

Use a regex that will accept [space]-/[space]


const hours = '13:00 - 17:00 / 20:00 - 02:00' 
const splitted = hours.split(/\s[-\/]\s/);

console.log(splitted)




I would use a match() approach here:


var hours = '13:00 - 17:00 / 20:00 - 02:00';
var times = hours.match(/\d{1,2}:\d{2}/g);
console.log(times);



This approach avoids the messiness in trying to articulate the required delimiters for splitting.

The regular expression / - | \/ / matches ' - ' and ' / ', which are the patterns separating the times in string.


const hours = '13:00 - 17:00 / 20:00 - 02:00';
const hoursArray = hours.split(/ - | \/ /);
console.log(hoursArray);






const hours = '13:00 - 17:00 / 20:00 - 02:00';
const matches=hours.match(/\d{2}:\d{2}/g);
console.log(matches);



Looks like you are trying to find the time format regardless of spaces or delimiters, suggesting to use match regex here
\d{2} >> will matche exactly 2 digits
: >>literal colon
\d{2} >> once more
